# Scala how to put elements in collection into array function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

So I have a dataframe, and a list of columns names that I need to put into array function so I can pass the names into a UDF using .withColumn function.

Like this: `val names = "col1,col2,col3"` and What I need is `array("col1","col2","col3")` . I have tried to make the names into a Seq and do a for loop like this:

```
array(for(i <- 0 to names.length-1)names(i))
```

but the problem is this for loop doesn't return any value. But if I do a for yield loop, then it's putting all the elements I want into a collection, but I need them to be extracted individually.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

To make the problem clearer....array is a function, not a collection. Array is the collection.

Example:

```
scala> array("col1","col2","col3")
res20: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = array(col1, col2, col3)
```

What I need: I have sequence `val names = Seq("col1","col2","col3")` and I need the element inside the Seq to be put into the array function.

Comment: `names.split(",")`

Comment: @philantrovert that's return me a collection, I don't need a collection

Comment: Your `array` and scala `Array` are different? What do you want if not an array?

Comment: can you provide input and expected output?

Comment: @philantrovert for scala 2.0 array is a function, Array is the collection, see my update pls

Comment: Oh, the dataframe `array`.

Comment: @philantrovert yes.. Any ideas? It really bothers me

Comment: @RameshMaharjan see my update please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.function.{col, array}

val names = "col1,col2,col3"

val cols = names.split(",").map(col(_))

val arrayCols = array(cols: _*)
```